# I am trying to connect my local server database(Mssql Database) to different database (Mssql but different table) using kafka connect?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Creating the source-connection.

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8083/connectors -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{    
    "name": "jdbc_source_mysql_01",     
    "config": {       
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",       
        "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://fulfillmentdbhost:3306/fulfillmentdb",       
        "connection.user": "fullfilment_user",       
        "connection.password": "<password>",       
        "topic.prefix": "order-status-update-",       
        "mode":"timestamp",       
        "table.whitelist" : "fulfullmentdb.status",       
        "timestamp.column.name": "LAST_UPDATED",       
        "validate.non.null": false     
    }   
}'
```

Creating the sink-connection.

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8083/connectors -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{    
    "name": "jdbc_sink_mysql_01",     
    "config": {       
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",       
        "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://crmdbhost:3306/crmdb",       
        "connection.user": "crm_user",       
        "connection.password": "<password>",       
        "topics": "order-status-update-status",       
        "table.name.format" : "crmdb.order_status"    
    }   
}'
```

the **`connector.class`** is given from confluent community. But I want it from Apache Kafka
Which is open source

we were searching how we can replace that line with apache kafka one.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no JDBC Connector [provided by Apache Kafka](https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/connect).

The Confluent one [is open source](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc).

There is also one [from IBM](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/kafka-connect-jdbc-sink) and [Aiven](https://github.com/aiven/jdbc-connector-for-apache-kafka)

Confluent (among other companies, as shown) simply write plugins for Kafka Connect, which you need to download/upgrade/install on your own Apache Kafka Connect servers.

Comment: Could you please tell us about MySQL Apache Kafka connector. & How to configure it

Comment: What about it? MySQL doesnt have a Kafka connector. As answered,  there are JDBC connectors, where you add the MySQL JAR file to it, or there is Debezium.

Comment: "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",  for apache kafka  what connector class should we use apart from Debezium and confluent

Comment: As answered, Kafka does not come with JDBC classes. Kafka itself doesn't care what `connector.class` are available on the classpath, as you manage those yourself... Other than Confluent or Debezium, you can use IBM one, or Aiven that are linked in my answer, or maybe others that exist.